# How to replace storyboard with an '.xib' file in coding

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode-storyboard

I found a UIPagecontrol example while googling and this works perfectly when i try to create this as a completely new project. Now i want to add this to my code

```
@interface filename2 ()

@end

@implementation filename2

@synthesize View1;
@synthesize View2;
@synthesize View3;



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
[super viewDidLoad];

[self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View1"]];
[self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View2"]];
[self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View3"]];




}


@end
```

But the problem I'm facing is that I'm not using storyboard I'm using ViewController.xib  so how can i change this code to use it with my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **initWithNibName**: Method for using xibs.

Example

```
ViewController *v1=[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
[self addChildViewController: v1]];
```

Comment: should i replace my whole body in viewDidLoad with this with v1 as view1? and add view2 and view 3 correspondingly?

Comment: Ok i did as you said and it is showing me all the views in my main View but I'm unable to add File's Owner to my view controller

Comment: Apperently i had to add the new UI as View not View Controller. And i was able to assign view1 , view2, view3 accordingly but when I'm running my project it always stops at Launch Image and doesn't move forward. What to do? It gives me this error "Could not load the image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier"

Answer (score 1):

Replace `[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View1"]` with object of your `ViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: owner: options:]

Xib is a Nib in xml format.